# Process.run() Permission denied

Tags: flutter, dart

When i try to run a dart file using Process.run();
its show a permission issue

Permission denied

```
Command: dart /data/user/0/com.flutterlearning.flutter_learning/code_cache/temp_dirENEWPV/temp.dart    _ProcessImpl._start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:402:33)
 Process.start (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:38:20)
_runNonInteractiveProcess (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:579:18)
 Process.run (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:49:12)
_CodeEditorState.runDartCode
```

Mostly i want to run code from tempFile, is it possile? if not possible, how can i run this type file,
I try this way, but don't know how to resolve,

```
dynamic runDartCode(String code) async {
var tempDir = Directory.systemTemp.createTempSync('temp_dir');
var tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/temp.dart');
try {
  tempFile.writeAsStringSync(code);

  // Execute the temporary Dart file using Dart VM
  var process = await Process.run('dart', [tempFile.path]);


  // Execute the temporary Dart file using Dart VM

  tempFile.deleteSync(); // Clean up temporary file

  // Return the output or error
  if (process.exitCode == 0) {
    return process.stdout;
  } else {
    throw process.stderr;
  }
}
catch(e,s){
  print(e);
  print(s);
}
}
```